# Persist changes immediately without save button in Xamarin.Forms apps

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, persistence

In Powerpoint Online for instance, you don't need to explicitly save your changes anymore.
It's done automatically.

Is there a best practice for accomplishing the same behaviour in a Xamarin.Forms app using a local sqlite database?

Currently I have "save" buttons that - once tapped - execute the respective viewmodels' save command which in turn uses the connected repositories' "AddOrUpdate" method to persist the whole model to the local sqlite database.

Comment: You could execute the save command when other events happen such as the completed event for entrys and editors or the selecteditemchanged for pickers.

Comment: most online tools that do this just run a timer and periodically save

Comment: In addition to one or both of the above suggestions, add Save code to app's `OnPause` method. This ensures state is saved before app goes to background (and possibly gets killed).

Comment: I am indeed thinking about automating the call to save whenever properties change or a model gets updates respectively. However, the hint to the OnPause override was valuable as I was not sure how to cope with the app going to the background.